# Find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix :
$A = $
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        5 & -2 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & -2 \\
        3 & 2 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$p(x) = ?$

So here's what I did :

$det(A-\lambda I)=0 $
$=$
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        5-\lambda & -2 & 0 \\
        0 & -1-\lambda & -2 \\
        3 & 2 & 0-\lambda \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Which gave me

$(5-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)(-\lambda)+12+4(5-\lambda)$

$p(x)=-x^3+4x^2+x+32$

Unfortunalty this isn't the right answer (I'm working with an automated system that corrects my homework). I've went threw each step very carefully but cannot find where the mistakes is!

Comment: By any chance, is $p(x) = x^3-4x^2-x-32$ the correct answer? If so, they may define $p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$.

Comment: Wow what. that worked. May I ask how am I suppose to know when to use $det(\lambda I - A) vs det(A - \lambda I) ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic%20polynomial%20%7B%7B5%2C-2%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C-2%7D%2C%7B3%2C2%2C0%7D%7D) confirms that your answer is correct. It's possible that the source you are using defines the characteristic polynomial as $\det(\lambda I-A)$ in which case the characteristic polynomial would be your answer multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: May I ask how am I suppose to know when to use det(λI−A)vsdet(A−λI)? I double checked and nothing about the definition (we didn't lean it this way and my book doesn't show it this way either).

Comment: I think that $\det(\lambda I-A)$ is more standard but you should consult whatever source you are using. Note that it doesn't matter if all you care about are the roots.

Answer (score 0):

Since det $(\lambda I - A) = 0$, there is nothing wrong in calculating det $(A - \lambda I)$, in your answer, $-x^3 + 4x^2 +x +32 =0$ ,multiply by -1 on both sides...